# how to return to main activity?

Tags: android

i have 4 activitys,and i want to move from the 4 activity to the main activity(the first one) when buttoon clicked.
i tried this code:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Menu.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
```

but it doesnt work,in the Logcat Appears to me the problem:"have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?"
if i call other activity it works.
please help!
(sorry about the bad english ^_^)
the manifest:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".Menu"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.tooti.fast.MAINACTIVITY" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TimeMode_Choose"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.tooti.fast.TIMEMODE_CHOOSE" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TimeMode"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.tooti.fast.TIMEMODE" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: and have you ? declared Menu activity in your manifest ?

Comment: yes,of course.you want me to add the manifest?

Answer (score 3):

Change the name of Activity - Menu.class , as  android has already view named  Menu  android.view.Menu

So Give some other name to your activity and try.

Answer (score 2):

There's a level of ambiguity there and you're probably confusing yourself, and Java.

Assuming that your `Menu` class is in fact declared in your manifest (Can you post that?), then ensure that your imports are accurate.

You'll be looking for:

`import com.yourpackage.Menu`

**and not**

`android.R.Menu` or `android.View.Menu`

**EDIT:** So now that you've posted your manifest, your code is wrong. You need:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of Activity - Menu.class with `Other name` and Register in `Androidmanifest.xml` 
and try like

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, OthernewName.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
```